# Ambiguous use of subscript in Json decode - Swift 2

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm trying to get the following json response from the server:

```
[{"m", "OK"}]
```

And I used the following code that works perfectly when I play in the simulator, but when I generate a archive to upload in the apple store it has the error

> Ambiguous use of 'subscript'

```
func funcao(completo: () -> Void, falha: () -> Void){
    let parametros = [
        "operacao" : "update",
        "tabela" : "1"
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, UrlServerPOST, parameters: parametros)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                print("JSON: \(JSON)")

                if let item = JSON[0] as? [String: String] { //Error here
                    if let resp = item["m"] as? String {
                        print(resp)
                        if resp == "OK" {
                            completo()
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            falha()
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        falha()
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    falha()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I tried several things to solve this error, but nothing solved. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: does `JSON` have a subscript operator? Or should you try to cast `JSON` to `[[String: String]]` first?

Comment: [[String: String]] did not work for me either @luk2302

Comment: Tell the compiler the type of `response.result.value`

Answer (score 1):

Every JSON object is either a dictionary or an array. You must tell Swift to subscript it with a key (as a dictionary) or with an integer index (as an array). Looks like `JSON` here is an array. Change this line:

```
if let JSON = response.result.value as? [AnyObject] {
    // ...
}
```